# BindingList AddingNew event not fired

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm struggling with the AddingNew event on BindingList.
This is my code: the ListChanged is fired, the AddingNew not.
I'm missing something?

```
{
    //....
    System.ComponentModel.BindingList<string> test = new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<string>();
    test.AllowNew = true;
    test.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
    test.AddingNew += Test_AddingNew;
    test.ListChanged += Test_ListChanged;
    test.Add(new string("test1"));
    test.Add("test2");
    //....
}

private void Test_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void Test_AddingNew(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AddingNewEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: AddingNew is ONLY fired when test.AddNew() is called. It is not called when test.Add() is called.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I was having the same issue. AddingNew is ONLY fired when BindingList.AddNew() is called. It is not called when BindingList.Add() is called.

Therefore either .ListChanged will need to be used or AddNew() will be required to fire the event.

Answer (score -1):

Its working for me, but what is this? - `new string("test1")`  <- remove it

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //....
        System.ComponentModel.BindingList<string> test = new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<string>();
        test.AllowNew = true;
        test.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
        test.AddingNew += Test_AddingNew;
        test.ListChanged += Test_ListChanged;
        test.Add("test1");
        test.Add("test2");
    }

    private static void Test_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static void Test_AddingNew(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AddingNewEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```